# Sections \label and \nameref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cmll}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amstext, amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}

 %========================================================
\begin{document}
\section{This is Header1 6.1.77} \label{6.1.77}
\subsection*{This is sub header}
.
.
.
.
.a document of 100 pages
.
.a document of various tables and other sections 
.
.
.recalled lables at various places through out the document,
\nameref{} entire section header appeared nicely. 

\end{document}
  %========================================================
```

Above code worked like a charm, I can use `\nameref{}` anywhere in the document and it created a hyperlink.
I went crazy and created as many as 3900 subsections and now the PDF prints only two pages and I get stack over flow error.
Hyperlinks appear as `??`.
I tried using `enumerate` and it does not hyperlink to specific line as it does in case of `\section{}`, also tried putting lines with labels and still it did not work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by “now the PDF prints only two pages and I get stack over flow error”. Have you gotten a PDF from TeX that your PDF viewer cannot handle? What exactly is the error you are seeing?

Comment: My crystal ball guesses: you have no text at all between those 3k subsections, hence there is no possibility for pagebreaks, on a TeX level, your second page becomes immensely long and breaks the ~400cm limit.

Comment: Your title does not reflect your question especially well.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, I agree that a little more information might be needed for that error but just a side note after glancing at your code: it's recommended that `\usepackage{hyperref}` comes last in the order of packages that you load.  occasionally a package requires placement after hyperref but i don't think there are many.  hyperref might get overwritten otherwise, so maybe you can see if that changes your hyperlink behavior any.

The hyperref [manual](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html) should have more info if you care to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

In case Ulrich's guess is right, you can give special permission to Latex to start new pages at sections, so:

```
\let\ursection=\section
\def\section{\pagebreak[0]\ursection}
```

(untested, since there is no MWE).

Comment: Another old unanswered qn.